# Anyone has the CCAvenue payment gateway extension for 1.9.2.1?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I have been trying to contact the developer team of the **CCAvenue** for 3 days now, but they are not replying.

Does anyone have the extension and can upload it for me please?

Would be really grateful.

Comment: Please follow this link.
[click here](https://www.magecloud.net/marketplace/extension/ccavenue-payment-gateway-2/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134004)

Comment: Its better to ask on Quora or other portal for such type of questions.

Comment: Thanks @CharulTyagi , I installed and set the extension, it's showing on both front-end and back-end, but however on trying to make a purchase the CCAvenue redirects to an error page - https://www.ccavenue.com/errorPages/Error.jsp?errorCode=0&processingFileName=ccavenue.txn.DoTransServlet&errorMessage=&cid=185692-100000044
Any idea what it can be?

Comment: @Jai Sure, I will keep in mind of that next time. Should I edit my question or something?

Comment: @CharulTyagi The version was probably backdated then CCAvenue version. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you buy `CCAvenue Payment Gateway` License,

then you can download Magento 1 extension from their dashboard after login.

I have also done same in past and that extension works well with `magento1`

Comment: Yes, you're right! I couldn't find the extension as at one place it was written to request the module from developer team. My bad, I should've checked more. For clearance I will add my answer on where how found it, if it helps future users.

Comment: The extensions for any CMS can be found on : Resources > Third-party shopping cart (It may vary in future updates)

Comment: @TayeabaMila , If my answer helps you then you can mark as accepted so it will help future readers